# xslt add number from regular expression to node value

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have the following xml snippet:

```
<STMTTRN><TRNTYPE>PAYMENT</TRNTYPE>
<DTPOSTED>20171120</DTPOSTED>
<TRNAMT>-645.29</TRNAMT>
<FITID>2017112049840000000061890000000035</FITID>
<MEMO>ARGO SEGUROS  PARC 03/05 SAO PAULO   BR</MEMO>
</STMTTRN>
```

And I'd like to add to the `DTPOSTED` node `x-1` months where `x` is the number indicated by the first two digits after `PARC` in the `MEMO` node as would be extracted by the regular expression (sed style)

```
PARC \([0-9][0-9]\)/[0-9][0-9]
```

So in the example above I'd like to obtain as output:

```
<STMTTRN><TRNTYPE>PAYMENT</TRNTYPE>
<DTPOSTED>20180120</DTPOSTED>
<TRNAMT>-645.29</TRNAMT>
<FITID>2017112049840000000061890000000035</FITID>
<MEMO>ARGO SEGUROS  PARC 03/05 SAO PAULO   BR</MEMO>
</STMTTRN>
```

I have no clue how to proceed and I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: As for the regular expression, why `PARC \(\d\d\)` with escaped `(` and `)` although the input does not contain any such characters in `PARC 03/05`? And if you want to use regular expressions and date arithmetics, can you use XSLT 2 or later?

Comment: I can use XSLT2 or later, and I corrected the regular expression to be as a 'sed' regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared an example script, showing step by step how to get the result you
want.

Because this script uses `xs` namespace, the `transform` tag must contain
`xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

It must contain also `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"`, otherwise the output
would have contained `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

The basic logic is contained in template matching `DTPOSTED`.
In my script it prints:

- Original content of `DTPOSTED`.
- All intermediate values (separated with `/`).
- The final value (shifted date string).

In your script omit any `xsl:value-of` except the last one and any
`xsl:text` used as separators.

And now let's get down to the details:

- `replace` function replaces the whole text with the content of
  the first capturing group, in your case `03`.
- To drop the leading `0`, I used `number` function, so now we have
  number of months to add (so far, not decreased).
- The duration string is composed of 3 parts:

  - `P` - period indicator,
  - the above number of months - 1,
  - 'M' - unit indicator (months).
- In order to perform date arithmetic, we need the original date,
  converted to `xs:date` type. I stored it in `d1` variable.
- The shifted date is computed according to formula
  `$d1 + xs:yearMonthDuration($dur)`. I stored it in `d2` variable.
- And the last stage is to print `$d2`, but without `-` chars.

So the whole script looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="DTPOSTED">
    <DTPOSTED>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/> <!-- Original value (string) -->
      <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
      <!-- Duration (string) -->
      <xsl:variable name="dur" select="concat('P', 
        number(replace(../MEMO,'\D+(\d\d)/.+','$1')) - 1, 'M')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$dur"/>
      <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
      <!-- Original value (date) -->
      <xsl:variable name="d1" select="xs:date(concat(substring(., 1, 4), '-',
        substring(., 5, 2), '-', substring(., 7, 2)))"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$d1"/>
      <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
      <!-- "Shifted" date -->
      <xsl:variable name="d2" select="$d1 + xs:yearMonthDuration($dur)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$d2"/>
      <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
      <!-- "Shifted" date without '-' chars -->
      <xsl:value-of select="format-date($d2, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/>
    </DTPOSTED>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For your sample source it prints `DTPOSTED` as:

```
<DTPOSTED>20171120 / P2M / 2017-11-20 / 2018-01-20 / 20180120</DTPOSTED>
```

As I noted before, it contains:

- `20171120` - original string.
- `P2M` - Period string.
- `2017-11-20` - original date.
- `2018-01-20` - shifted date (with `-` chars).
- `20180120` - shifted date as a string, without `-` chars.

Actually you need only the last from the above prinouts.

Comment: Thanks, after a first test this seems to work for me!